# Search for "not newline" in vim?

Tags: vim, regular-expression

To search for `A T\n` in vim I can just do

```
/A T\n
```

What would be the equivalent for not newline at the end?

```
/A T[^\n]
```

did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/A T.
```

searches for `A T` followed by a non-newline character (`.` is the standard regex operator that matches any character (except newline)).

```
/A T\n\@!
```

searches for `A T` not-followed by a newline character (you'll see the difference if you `set hls`). `\@!` is a vim-specific regexp operator that provides with similar functionality as the `(?!...)` perl/PRCE regexp operator (negative look-ahead). That one would work in the case of a non-text file that ends in `A T` (and no newline).

You could also use the positive look-ahead:

```
/A T.\@=
```

(`A T` as long as it's followed by a non-newline character).

You can also do:

```
/A T\ze.
```

Same as `/A T.` except that the end of the *matched* string is after the `T`. `\zs` and `\ze` are again `vim` specific and can be used to narrow the *matched* string (as seen with highlight search) within the pattern. The perl/PCRE equivalent of `\zs` is `\K` (in recent versions).

Having said that, `/A T[^\n]` works for me (vim 7.4.52), though `[...]` would never match a newline anyway (you'd need `\_[...]` to include the newline), so `.` is simpler.